# how to return rect values from def function in a class in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

In this code, i get different sprites from a list and blit it onto the screen. in the process, the rect of the image is also taken. but i want to know how i can return the rect value so i can use it for collisions and stuff. here's the part of the code that handles the animations:

```
def animation_walking(self, direction_x, direction_y, listName):
    if self.dir_y == direction_y and self.dir_x == direction_x and self.idleanim == False:
        sprite = listName[int(self.current_sprite)]
        self.current_sprite += self.animationspeed
        if self.current_sprite >= len(listName):
            self.current_sprite = 0
        screen.blit(sprite, (self.posX, self.posY))
        rect = sprite.get_rect(topleft=(self.posX, self.posY)) # the value i want to return
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the rectangle or `None`

```py
def animation_walking(self, direction_x, direction_y, listName):
    if self.dir_y == direction_y and self.dir_x == direction_x and self.idleanim == False:
        sprite = listName[int(self.current_sprite)]
        self.current_sprite += self.animationspeed
        if self.current_sprite >= len(listName):
            self.current_sprite = 0
        
        rect = sprite.get_rect(topleft=(self.posX, self.posY))
        screen.blit(sprite, rect)
        return rect

    return None
```

Alternatively save the rectangle in a `self.rect` attribute and return the rectangle:

```py
def __init__(self):
    # [...]
    self.rect = None

def animation_walking(self, direction_x, direction_y, listName):
    if self.dir_y == direction_y and self.dir_x == direction_x and self.idleanim == False:
        sprite = listName[int(self.current_sprite)]
        self.current_sprite += self.animationspeed
        if self.current_sprite >= len(listName):
            self.current_sprite = 0
        
        self.rect = sprite.get_rect(topleft=(self.posX, self.posY))
        screen.blit(sprite, self.rect)

    return self.rect
```

Comment: It's not clear you need to return the value *and* store it as an instance attribute.